# XPath for html elements

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I'd like to use [Scrapy](https://scrapy.org/) to crawl a few hundred websites and just scrape the basic (title, meta* and body) html elements. I know that I should use [CrawlSpider](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#crawlspider) for this and adjust some of the settings based on [broad crawls](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/broad-crawls.html#broad-crawls). The part that I'm having trouble figuring it out is how to use xpath to create the rules for scraping just those basic html elements. Lots of tutorials I see involve inspecting the element and finding the css class for that element. That is fine for the body element but what about the title and meta tags?

Comment: What have you tried? Have you written any code to try yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There XPath and CSS selector you can use to select nodes in HTML.
the element is a node, but the node not always an element.
So, then you know *head*, *meta*, *body* are all elements. the *class* attributes in the div is the same as the *charset* attribute in meta element. They are all attributes nodes.

e.g:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang='zh-cn'>
  <head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="renderer" content="webkit">
    <title>title</title> 
  </head>
  <body>   
     <div>website content</div> 
  </body>
</html>
```

if you want to select

```
<meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
```

you can use XPATH like this:

```
//head/meta[@http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can search the elements in `<head>` the same way you find in `<body>`, for example:

```
//html/head/title
```

or

```
//html/head/meta
```

Answer (score 0):

Well for the title node you can write a simple XPath expression : `//title` which is the abbreviated syntax of `/descendant-or-self::node()/child::title`  and that's it.
For the meta node guess what you can just write `//meta` too or if you want you can use the absolute path `/html/head/meta`

PS. You can do the same thing for the body node.